# Why does running MLlib project in IntelliJ IDEA fail with "AssertionError: assertion failed: unsafe symbol CompatContext"?

Tags: java, apache-spark, regression, apache-spark-mllib

I'm trying to run the Logistic Regression example (https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/ml/JavaLogisticRegressionWithElasticNetExample.java)

This is the code:

```
public final class GettingStarted {

public static void main(final String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "C:\\winutils");

    SparkSession spark = SparkSession
            .builder()
            .appName("JavaLogisticRegressionWithElasticNetExample")
            .config("spark.master", "local")
            .getOrCreate();

    // $example on$
    // Load training data
    Dataset<Row> training = spark.read().format("libsvm").load("data/mllib/sample_libsvm_data.txt");

    LogisticRegression lr = new LogisticRegression()
            .setMaxIter(10)
            .setRegParam(0.3)
            .setElasticNetParam(0.8);

    // Fit the model
    LogisticRegressionModel lrModel = lr.fit(training);

    // Print the coefficients and intercept for logistic regression
    System.out.println("Coefficients: "
            + lrModel.coefficients() + " Intercept: " + lrModel.intercept());

    // We can also use the multinomial family for binary classification
    LogisticRegression mlr = new LogisticRegression()
            .setMaxIter(10)
            .setRegParam(0.3)
            .setElasticNetParam(0.8)
            .setFamily("multinomial");

    // Fit the model
    LogisticRegressionModel mlrModel = mlr.fit(training);

    // Print the coefficients and intercepts for logistic regression with multinomial family
    System.out.println("Multinomial coefficients: " + lrModel.coefficientMatrix()
            + "\nMultinomial intercepts: " + mlrModel.interceptVector());
    // $example off$

    spark.stop();}}
```

I'm also using the same file of the example (https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/data/mllib/sample_libsvm_data.txt)
But I get these errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: unsafe symbol CompatContext (child of package macrocompat) in runtime reflection universe
at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.<init>(Symbols.scala:184)
at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$TypeSymbol.<init>(Symbols.scala:2984)
at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$ClassSymbol.<init>(Symbols.scala:3176)
at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$StubClassSymbol.<init>(Symbols.scala:3471)
at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.newStubSymbol(Symbols.scala:498)
at scala.reflect.internal.pickling.UnPickler$Scan.readExtSymbol$1(UnPickler.scala:258)
at scala.reflect.internal.pickling.UnPickler$Scan.readSymbol(UnPickler.scala:284)
at scala.reflect.internal.pickling.UnPickler$Scan.readSymbolRef(UnPickler.scala:649)
at scala.reflect.internal.pickling.UnPickler$Scan.readType(UnPickler.scala:417)
at scala.reflect.internal.pickling.UnPickler$Scan$LazyTypeRef$$anonfun$6.apply(UnPickler.scala:725)
at scala.reflect.internal.pickling.UnPickler$Scan$LazyTypeRef$$anonfun$6.apply(UnPickler.scala:725)
at scala.reflect.internal.pickling.UnPickler$Scan.at(UnPickler.scala:179)
at scala.reflect.internal.pickling.UnPickler$Scan$LazyTypeRef.completeInternal(UnPickler.scala:725)
at scala.reflect.internal.pickling.UnPickler$Scan$LazyTypeRef.complete(UnPickler.scala:749)
at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.info(Symbols.scala:1489)
at scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$$anon$12.scala$reflect$runtime$SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$$super$info(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:162)
at scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$$anonfun$info$1.apply(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:127)
at scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$$anonfun$info$1.apply(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:127)
at scala.reflect.runtime.Gil$class.gilSynchronized(Gil.scala:19)
at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaUniverse.gilSynchronized(JavaUniverse.scala:16)
at scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$class.gilSynchronizedIfNotThreadsafe(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:123)
at scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$$anon$12.gilSynchronizedIfNotThreadsafe(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:162)
at scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$class.info(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:127)
at scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$$anon$12.info(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:162)
at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.ensureClassSymbol(Mirrors.scala:94)
at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getClassByName(Mirrors.scala:102)
at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getClassIfDefined(Mirrors.scala:114)
at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getClassIfDefined(Mirrors.scala:111)
at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.BlackboxContextClass$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:496)
at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.BlackboxContextClass(Definitions.scala:496)
at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaUniverseForce$class.force(JavaUniverseForce.scala:305)
at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaUniverse.force(JavaUniverse.scala:16)
at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaUniverse.init(JavaUniverse.scala:147)
at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaUniverse.<init>(JavaUniverse.scala:78)
at scala.reflect.runtime.package$.universe$lzycompute(package.scala:17)
at scala.reflect.runtime.package$.universe(package.scala:17)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.<init>(ScalaReflection.scala:40)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.<clinit>(ScalaReflection.scala)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.RowEncoder$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$encoders$RowEncoder$$serializerFor(RowEncoder.scala:74)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.RowEncoder$.apply(RowEncoder.scala:61)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:67)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.baseRelationToDataFrame(SparkSession.scala:415)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:172)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:156)
at GettingStarted.main(GettingStarted.java:95)
```

Do you know what I'm wrong about?

EDIT:
I run it on IntelliJ, it is a Maven project and I added the dependencies:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-spark-connector_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: IntelliJ
it is a Maven project

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr** As soon as you start seeing errors internal to scala, mentionning reflection universe, think incompatible scala versions.

Your scala versions on your libs do not match one another (2.10 and 2.11).

You should align all on your actual scala version.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId> <!-- This is scala v2.11 -->
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.10</artifactId> <!-- This is scala v2.10 -->
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```